# Is there a faster way to check for a bunch of things in a list/set?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, set

I have to check if numbers 1 to 9 are in a list/set

```
if 1 in factor_numbers and 2 in factor_numbers and 3 in factor_numbers and 4 in factor_numbers and 5 in factor_numbers and 6 in factor_numbers and 7 in factor_numbers and 8 in factor_numbers and 9 in factor_numbers and 0 in factor_numbers:
```

There has to be a more efficient way to do this check? The numbers do not necessarily appear adjacent to each other

Comment: What are the other possible elements?

Comment: random integers

Comment: `all(n in factor_numbers for n in numbers)` ? or just write a loop?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In which way this is more efficient?

Comment: @Selcuk in the way that you don't have to write it all out by hand. Which is the only way I can interpret "efficiently" here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Makes sense. I interpreted it as CPU efficiency though.

Comment: That may be the case, but I doubt it. I see very little evidence that is a consideration here. Perhaps the OP can clarify when they provide a [mcve]

Comment: I meant it the way juanpa interpreted it, but better CPU efficiency is always a bonus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the defined method `set.issubset` defined for sets, such that:

```py
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]).issubset(set(factor_numbers))
```

Comment: I may or may not have misunderstood your question. Can you provide a concrete example of what is not working as you want?

Comment: I made a mistake, didn't include 0, and deleted my comment. This works perfectly.

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: What's the advantage of set.issubset over a simple <= or < operator?

Comment: The main advantage is of clarity. in the sense that looking at the code, it is obvious what `issubset` means. On the contrary, `<=` on a set probably means you have to go through the docs to understand what the code is doing. Under the hood, both are equivalent.